# Open Office Calc:Convert list of text urls into links

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have a list of text urls in, how i can convert all of them into clickable links?

Comment: Not programming related, at all!

Comment: Tahnk you for comment but i think that script that script would be a programing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HYPERLINK(linkaddress; celltext)
```

Comment: The result is quite different from the result one obtains when one explicity does "Insert > Hyperlink". That's damned inconsistent.

Answer (score 4):

HYPERLINK does not solve the problem. As a result, we will have two columns: the original and the results of the formula. The question was how to CONVERT urls into clickable links. My method:
1. Cut the column from calc.
2. Paste as plain text into writer (shift-ctrl-v).
3. Format > AutoCorrect > Apply.
4. Copy links back to calc.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you found a solution in the 6+ years since your question, but it may help others searching for the same solution.

Converting them in `openoffice-calc` is a cumbersome process.

It's much easier to copy them to `openoffice-writer` and covert them there, then copy them back:

1. Copy and paste the list of urls into a `openoffice-writer` document.
2. From the `Format` menu, choose `AutoCorrect`, then `AutoCorrect Options...`
3. On the `Options` tab, click both the `[M]` and `[T]` boxes next to
   `URL Recognition` and click the `OK` button.
4. Select the list, go to `Format` > `AutoCorrect` > `Apply`.
5. Copy the url list back to `openoffice-calc`.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: For LibreOffice 7.2.5.2.0 (and probably some similar versions) the `AutoCorrect` item is under `Tools` and has subitems, from which you need to select `Apply`.